# Geolocation form not waiting callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm trying to make the geolocation form allow, block to appear after a function has finished running. At this moment, even by using a callback, the geolocation doesn't wait the the Jquery action to complete.

I'm using the typeIt jquery plugin to make some text appear, and after the text has all appeared, then the geolocation box should be shown to the users.

This is what I have right now:

```
function typeThen(callback) {
    $(".text").typeIt({
        speed: 30,
        cursor: false
    })
    .tiType("Meow! ")
    .tiPause(1000)
    .tiBreak()
    .tiType("Please, share your location with us. Oh, and don't be afraid... ")
    .tiPause(750)
    .tiType("cats are very good at keeping secrets! :3")

    callback && callback();
}

function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendLocation, geoError);
}

typeThen(function(){
    getLocation();
});
```

Comment: Well you're not waiting for anything to complete, you're launching the callback right away. Then the first `.tiPause()`, (whatever this is) starts waiting for 1000ms.

Comment: Why? Shouldn't the callback be called after the typeIt function has finished running all its commands?

Comment: It should, precisely. But this is not the case. You're not encapsulating it at the end of your command chain. Try `.then(callback)`

Comment: if I put the .then after the last .tiType, then I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeIt(...).tiType(...).tiPause(...).tiBreak(...).tiType(...).tiPause(...).tiType(...).then is not a function
    at typeThen (index.html:52)
    at index.html:82

Comment: `.tiPause(1000)` doesn't stop the execution of the script. Javascript is not PHP, it's not executed line by line. While something waits, the next instruction (in that case `callback()`) is executed immediately.

Comment: Ok. Then how can I tell it to wait until it finishes all the type actions, and then make the box appear? Is there a way? I also tried with .when .then, but no luck, the box appears as the page finishes loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [TypeIt documentation](https://github.com/alexmacarthur/typeit) :

> callback - (function) A function that executes after your typing has
>   completed.

So just use that :

```
$(".text").typeIt({
        speed: 30,
        cursor: false,
        callback : function(){
            callback()
         })
    })
```

Or even simply :

```
$(".text").typeIt({
        speed: 30,
        cursor: false,
        callback : callback
    })
```